# Magento Community 1.9.1 RWD theme: Home page "add to cart" failure

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, rwd-theme, home

I just noticed that when I used the 'add to cart' button on the home page of my site, it doesn't work in Firefox or IE.... it only brings me to an empty cart. It does work in Chrome however. I've cleared the caches so I know it's not a cache problem? Please confirm and advise. tia

Update: It doesn't work in chrome either. after further investigating, I found that that If I disable the Cache management setting : Blocks HTML output... it works fine. I turned it off for now. I can turn it back on for debugging.

http://kaleidoscopiacoloringbooks.com/Store/

Comment: I take that back... doens't work in chrome either.  after further investigating, I found that that If I disable the Cache management setting : Blocks HTML output... it works fine. I turned it off for now. I can turn it back on for debugging.

Comment: You should provide some more information like: What modifications did you do, how did you set up the homepage-products, what caching mechanisms do you use etc.

Comment: I didn't do any modifications from the defaults except for some CSS changes and some changes to Mod Rewrite (to get rid of "index.php" from my urls). I set the home page to use "Catalog New Products list" widget. I'm guessing there's a bug with how caching is being used on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cache problem on New Block.
On Cms you can add new block like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" _productsCount="8" cache_lifetime="1"}}
```

Or you can add to xml file.
Add a cache block, in xml layout (cms.xml or page.xml) page where new product blongs.

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="newproducts" products_count="20" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">

<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>  // add this line
```